# Solving multiple equations using scipy.optimize.minimize in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I see the solution to solve a minimization problem as suggested here: [Numpy: Linear system with specific conditions. No negative solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968955/numpy-linear-system-with-specific-conditions-no-negative-solutions)

But I have 'k' such minimization problems to be solved at a point. So instead of iterating through each of the 'k', I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this in numpy? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If they are *independent*, iterating is the way to go and combining them would probably be slower.

I also don't think the approach used in this answer is the fastest one. It's using a much more complex algorithm needed, which is tailored for a much broader case.
I would try [nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html#scipy.optimize.nnls) which should be superior (in most cases) in regards to solving-time and robustness!

It could be possible, that the Fortran-implementation of scipy's nnls is not multithreaded. In this case, because you might have many independent problems, you can easily solve them in parallel using [joblib for example](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html).

The only thing left to mention: if your problems are sparse, you should look for algorithms optimized for the sparse-case!

(In the case where your problems might be similar somehow, there is much more gain possible, but probably not without an own implementation which for example reuses matrix-factorizations. But i don't think you want to pursue this as it will get complex very fast)