# Solving a system of constrained linear equations

Tags: python, least-squares, linear-equation

I need to solve a large system of linear equations using a least squares method. So far I have found the answers whilst unconstrained but would like to limit my answers to be non-negative. The code I have been using is shown below. 'Sheet 1' holds a matrix of size 30x135 and 'sheet 2' a matrix of size 30x1.

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 df = pd.read_excel("C:\\example\price_analysis.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet1")
 print(df)
 dg = pd.read_excel("C:\\example\price_analysis.xlsx", sheet_name = "Sheet2")
 print(dg)
 z = np.linalg.lstsq(df,dg, rcond=None)
 print(z)
```

I tried using the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968955/numpy-linear-system-with-specific-conditions-no-negative-solutions) post but couldn't work out how to find the least squares result where all values are positive, rather than simply changing all negative values to be 0.

Comment: That's a linear programming problem, and NumPy alone may not be able to solve this. `scipy`, on the other hand, should have methods to do it.

Comment: This is not an LP as the objective is nonlinear. The natural scipy-func would be [nnls](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.nnls.html). But you could also use some of the `scipy.optimize.minimize` solvers as outlined in your link, but in this case: pass gradients (and don't use numerical differentiation as done in the link). The former will be faster and more simple for small / dense instances. For large / sparse instances, L-BFGS-B within `minimize` will be much much faster.

Comment: Check out this thread as well: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/18258/how-to-force-weights-to-be-non-negative-in-linear-regression

Comment: Thanks all, the nnls method seems to be a good way to solve my problem. I've got it to work for an example data set but can't get it to work when I'm pulling my data in from excel:

Thanks you again